# Can the xlrd module change the file properties?

Tags: python, excel, properties, xls, xlrd

Can the xlrd module change the file propeties? Such as author,title,subject,etc..
I want to change a .xls file's properties and don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know that's not possible with `xlrd`. The `rd` part of the name means "read-only". You would need to use the `xlwt` library for writing or one of the newer options like `XlsxWriter`.

Comment: the XlsxWriter module can't do that for me, and i didn't find anything from the xlwt module where i can change the properties, anyways, Thanks for the help <3